# How to upload screenshots?

Tags: support, images, screenshot

How do I upload pictures to the site? I saw the `<img>` tag on a list of basic HTML so I tried:

```
<img src="C:\TOM Files\downloads\cakephpscreenshot.jpg" />
```

but it doesn't work. I think adding some screenshots will better help in presenting my questions.

Comment: That is a local address, that is that it is only on your machine. Try uploading it to an image host (such as [imgur](http://imgur.com)) and linking it that way.

Comment: This is going to be difficult

Comment: Looks like it wasn't that difficult @Juan

Comment: @qnt I'm glad I was wrong :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Head to the toolbar on top of the message editor. Press the last button on the 2nd button group with the `Image` tooltip.

---

[image]

---

Click it and then press `Browse...` button to locate the image and then press `Upload` button.

---

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You click on the little image icon and it will ask you whether you wan to upload to a image hosting site, or to SO directly. Do what you wish.

SO uploads it to [imgur.com](http://imgur.com), an image hosting site, so it doesn't make a difference where you shove it, so it'll display fine from anywhere.

Comment: Thaks for the info... Its the first time I heard about imgur.com.

Comment: I love the way you can drag and drop like 50 images into the browser window to download. It's quite useful.