# How can I upload an image to use it in a comment?

Tags: feature-request, support, comments, images

I needed to reference an image in a [comment to an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9952494/183704), but it's not possible to upload a picture in a comment. So I used the workaround to [edit the answer post, upload the image](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/91719/195083) and delete the added image and text in the answer, ending up with a *stack.imgur.com* image link. I did this because the [image is related to the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/145826/195083).

Why it's not possible to upload an image in a comment?

Comment: That's a good enough workaround, why would you need anything more?

Comment: I think it's a usability fail because it's inconvenient.

Comment: Well, true, but how often do you really need to include an image in a comment?

Comment: I don't know, how often I need that, but I know I needed that in [my first stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9908148/openrdf-sesame-database-triplestore-in-eclipse-wtp-project-with-tomcat).

Comment: Hm, I think that image should go into the question itself...

Comment: Hmm, but the is related the the answer.

Comment: Edit your answer and write something like "I tried Jeen Broekstra's suggestion, but I get these errors" and include the image. It might only be relevant to the one answer, but it provides information that others' might pick up on and help you find a solution.

Comment: Okay, I do that.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't add the image to your question because it is not relevant for the question itself, you can start writing an answer, and add the image to the answer using the post toolbar. You copy the link to the uploaded image, and use it to write your comment, writing the link as `[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXfJu.png)`, for example. After you copied the link, you can discard the answer you wrote using the "discard" link. The link doesn't appear immediately; if you don't see it, wait some seconds, and it will appear.

As suggested by [Yannis Rizos](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/162704/yannis-rizos), I would rather write that in the question, as it is relevant for everybody who answers your question. Clearly, I would not write "I tried what @username suggested, and it doesn't work for me" for every user who answers the question, but I would add a note in the question if I can give more information that can be useful to who answers the question.