# How to add pictures to the added comments in this website

Tags: support, comments, images

I asked a question, but I needed to show the person who answered my question a picture of how did I apply what he/she mentioned.

I could not add a picture to the comment and that made me unable to put my comment in shape.

Comment: Why should a _comment_ contain pictures?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ The question is about comments, not answers and questions.

Comment: You can start writing a draft to another post (question or answer), upload the image there and copy the image ulr to your comment. Don't submit the other post. (Bonus: you might get one of these fancy X-mas hats for starting a draft but not submitting it...)

Comment: Related: [How can I upload an image to use it in a comment?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/145994). (Maybe also [other questions linked there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/145994).)

Comment: Sometimes pictures are useful, but in many cases it's better to post text. In particular, please don't post images of text, as discussed here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4014959

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't upload an image to a comment. You can however always edit your own post to include an attempt you made or clarify where you are stuck. That is important information for the question and therefor this should go in the post, not in a comment. If that textual clarification is better supported with an image, then by all means [upload one in the post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post).

If you really, really, really want to add an image link to a comment, you can upload an image into to any post (I often use an new answer or new question for that) and then grab the url of that image and copy-paste it into my comment. Don't submit the actual post you (ab)used for this.

Comment: Here is an example of how such image would go into a comment  https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vw7ps.gif

Answer (score 3):

Why would you need an image in a comment? You can post a link to your image like this:

`Hello, here is my [image](https://apifriends.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/Screen-Shot-2018-04-27-at-1.01.14-PM-696x338.png)`

This won't flood comments, and still provide an image link. If somebody asks you to upload an image on your question, just edit the question and add image like it is [described here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post), to avoid others asking for this image. If it is on your answer, post a link if you don't really need this image, or upload it to the answer if it will help others.

Comment: Hello, here is my [image](https://apifriends.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/Screen-Shot-2018-04-27-at-1.01.14-PM-696x338.png)

Answer (score 1):

If you got an answer and it didn't solve your problem, the correct course of action is to either edit your question to include the image; Or open a new question, with the image, and  also a link to the previous question and an explanation on why the answers there were not enough.

The advantage of the second method is that you don't invalidate answers (which justifies a rollback of your question edits). Which one you should do depends on context, though.

Also consider that if you have to add images after getting answers, your question probably wasn't perfectly defined from the start. Consider investing more time on future questions, for the better the question asked, the better the answers you get.